# I am not getting the last ID in MySQL and Node

Tags: mysql, node.js, wordpress

I have a problem that I have not been able to solve since yesterday, it is the code that I will put below, but I wanted to make precisions, I have 2 tables, wp posts and wp post meta, I try to get the last id of a post and then insert according to that, for  I use promises that, but the last function "insertlink" is not returning the last id, it says it is not defined, I don't understand, thanks.

```
function insertarpost()

{
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  var sql = "INSERT INTO `wp_posts` ( `post_author`, `post_date`, `post_date_gmt`, `post_content`, `post_title`,`post_excerpt`, `post_status`,`comment_status`, `ping_status`,`post_password`, `post_name`,`to_ping`,`pinged`, `post_modified`, `post_modified_gmt`,`post_content_filtered`,`post_parent`, `guid`,`menu_order`, `post_type`, `post_mime_type`,`comment_count`) VALUES (1, '"+fhoy+"', '"+fhoy+"', '"+description+"', '"+title+"','', 'publish', 'open', 'closed','','"+slug+"','','', '"+fhoy+"', '"+fhoy+"','', '0','','0', 'movies','' ,0);";
  con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
    if (err)  throw err;
    resolve(result);
    console.log("1 registro insertado");
  });

});
}




insertarpost().then(obtenerultimopostid);

function obtenerultimopostid() {
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  con.query("SELECT ID FROM wp_posts ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 0,1;", function (err, result, fields) {
  console.log(result);
    var sql = "INSERT INTO wp_postmeta (post_id, meta_key, meta_value) VALUES ("+result[0].ID+",'runtime', '"+runtime+"'),("+result[0].ID+",'original_title','"+titleoriginal+"'),("+result[0].ID+",'Rated','"+cpgrated+"'),("+result[0].ID+",'Country', '"+country+"'),("+result[0].ID+",'date', '"+datemovie+"'),("+result[0].ID+",'imdbRating', '"+repimdb+"'),("+result[0].ID+",'vote_average', '"+reptmdb+"'),("+result[0].ID+",'imdbVotes', '"+quantimdb+"'),("+result[0].ID+",'vote_count', '"+quanttmdb+"'),("+result[0].ID+",'tagline', '"+tagline+"'),("+result[0].ID+",'dt_poster', '"+poster+"'),("+result[0].ID+",'dt_backdrop', '"+backdrop+"'),("+result[0].ID+",'imagenes', '"+backdrops+"'),("+result[0].ID+",'dt_cast', '"+textimgreparto+"'),("+result[0].ID+",'dt_dir', '"+textimgreparto2+"');";
  con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    resolve(result);
    console.log("1 registro wpmeta insertado");
  });

});
  });  

}
obtenerultimopostid().then(insertarlink);


var idultimomovie='';


  function insertarlink() {
var sql ="SELECT ID FROM wp_posts ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 0,1;";
con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
    if (err)  throw err;
    idultimomovie=result[0].ID;
    console.log(idultimomovie);
  });

    for(var i=0;i<getData.length;i++) {

    var source=getData[i]['source'];
    var text =getData[i]['text'];
    var quality = getData[i]['quality'];

var sql = "INSERT INTO `wp_posts` ( `post_author`, `post_date`, `post_date_gmt`, `post_content`, `post_title`,`post_excerpt`, `post_status`,`comment_status`, `ping_status`,`post_password`, `post_name`,`to_ping`,`pinged`, `post_modified`, `post_modified_gmt`,`post_content_filtered`,`post_parent`, `guid`,`menu_order`, `post_type`, `post_mime_type`,`comment_count`) VALUES (1, '"+fhoy+"', '"+fhoy+"', '', '"+make+"','', 'publish', 'closed', 'closed','','"+make+"','','', '"+fhoy+"', '"+fhoy+"','', '"+idultimomovie+"','','0', 'dt_links','' ,0);";
  con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
    if (err)  throw err;
    console.log("1 registro link insertado");
  });
}
}
```

Comment: I don't understand, when I delete the function 'insertlink' or leave it alone with a simple message of 'console.log ()' I get an error, it's as if there is something wrong with just naming it.

Comment: Is formatting prohibited in node.js?

Answer (score 0):

Using `SELECT ID ... ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1` to find the value to use for your followon insertions is, with respect, **error-prone and a bad idea**. If more than one client to your MySQL server tries to do this sort of thing at once, you'll have a race condition that may deliver the wrong ID values.

You need to use [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) or one of its variants.  The [npm mysql package lets you use `result.insertId`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#getting-the-id-of-an-inserted-row) for this purpose.

You could do something like this in your code.

```
function insertarpost()  {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var sql = "INSERT INTO `wp_posts` whatever...;";
        con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
            if (err)  throw err;
            console.log ('ID to use for wp_postmeta', result.insertId)
            resolve(result);
        } );
    } );
}

function obtenerultimopostid(previousResult) {
    /* you get the result from the previous promise in previousResult */
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var postId = previousResult.insertId
        var sql = "INSERT INTO wp_postmeta (post_id, meta_key, meta_value) VALUES (" + postId + ", .... whatever )";
        con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;
            resolve(result);
        } );
    } );
}

insertarpost().then(obtenerultimopostid);
```

Notice how the value in `resolve(result)` in your first Promise function is passed as the parameter to your second Promise function.

**Pro tip** Always indent your code. If you don't want to do it yourself, use an IDE like Visual Studio Code or Webstorm, or a good text editor. Why? Easier to read.

**Pro tip 2** Parameterize your SQL statements.  Use something like this:

```
var sql = "INSERT INTO wp_postmeta (post_id, meta_key, meta_value) VALUES (?, ?, ?)"
var postId = previousResult.insertId;
var key = "whatever";
var val = "whatelse";
con.query (sql, [postId, key, value], function (err, result) {
    /* whatever */
} );
```

Why? Much easier to read, and less vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).